# Views: expose filter - filter out results between a specific set of dates

Tags: 7, views

I have a views (content type = car, Create date filter"exposed" and some fields to display in the result in a table).

is there any way to display all the node not created in the date that selected using the filter?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a view filter that uses the operator of "Is not between" when referencing a date.

You can have multiple filters for the same value, so you could allow people to search for dates, but have a second filter that removes results between X and Y

Comment: is there a way to use single filter not a multiple filter? or can i write a relative date that return start date filter value (start date = end date)?

Comment: not as far as I know.  you will have to use 2 filters.